# Bluetooth scanning for devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a problem with my code:

```
private ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback(){
    //Callback when a BLE advertisement has been found.
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

       new Thread(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               final BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       if (device != null){
                           mDevices.add(device);
                       }
                   }
               });
           }
       }.start();

    }

    //Callback when batch results are delivered.
    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
    }

    //Callback when scan could not be started.
    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
    }
```

currently I am using this code to get the results of my scan. This was based on: https://github.com/RedBearLab/Android/blob/master/Examples/Chat/src/com/redbear/chat/Main.java#L138

The app where is was based on had a lower API level, and my app has a higher one. So I changed it to on startScan() method.

I am honestly stuck, because when I run the app i get no errors. I checked if the mDevices array is empty and it is. Meaning that the code doesn't add the devices to the array or that there aren't any devices to be found by my app specifically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code of activating scanning

```
private void scanDevice(){
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            BTScanner.startScan(mLeScanCallback);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(SCAN_PERIOD);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BTScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }


    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It has to do with the permissions for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to get the scan results.

Comment: I have added the permissions but i didn't get the device name